# How can I sum up values in my mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model in `mongoose` that looks similar to this:

```
var TestSchema = new Schema({
    test_username: {type: String, required: true},
    test_content: {type: String},
    reactions: [{
        test_username: {type: String, required: true},
        value: {type: Number, required: true},
        sent_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now}
    }],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updated_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
 })
```

it stores my `Test` object with many reactions in it. Each reaction contains either `1` or `-1` `value` and different usernames. 
Now I'm trying to create an endpoint that gets the `Test` id as an input and returns the total, summed amount from all reactions that it contains.

I started writing it as:

```
testRoutes.get('/:id/reactions/', functions.validateRequestsGET, function(req, res){
    var testId = req.params.id;

    var query = Test... //here I'm stuck

    query.exec(function(err, reactions){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }

        res.json(reactions);
    });
});
```

can you give me a hint of how to create a query that could return me a json with the summed amount? something like `{reactions: 17}` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Test.aggregate(
    { $match: {
        _id: testId // you might want to convert this from string to ObjectId()
    }},    
    { $project: {
        sumReactions: { $sum: "$reactions.value" }
    }}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at group accumulators [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) in documentation , good examples too.